# i need to change the backcolor of the selected item in listview with multiple columns

Tags: c#, listview

As the title goes. I already implemented this in listbox. now i want to implement this to listview with multiple columns. can you also include drawcolumnheader example?

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

`ListView` (in winforms) is tied to the win32 control. If you want more flexibility, I would switch to `DataGridView`; this still lets you display tabular data, but you can change the styling at various levels of granularity.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just getting started with a ListView, do yourself a favor and have a look at [ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/objectlistview.aspx). ObjectListView is an open source wrapper around .NET WinForms ListView, which makes it **much** easier to use, as well as easily allowing things that are very difficult in a normal ListView.

Changing the backcolor of the selected item is an example of something that is difficult in a normal ListView but easy with an ObjectListView. In a normal ListView, the background of selected rows is controlled by the system -- you cannot change it to anything else. But with an ObjectListView, you just do this:

```
this.objectListView1.OwnerDraw = true;
this.objectListView1.HighlightBackgroundColor= Color.Red;
```

Also, out of the box, the ObjectListView allows you to change the font and text color of the column header. You can even word wrap the column header if you want:

[image]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/_images/header-formatting.png))</sub>